# Subnodes on border of ellipsis

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-node

I want to place some subnodes on the border of a node. This is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle, draw, inner sep=10pt] (Foo) {Foo};
    \node[rectangle, draw, fill=white, left=3pt of Foo.south] {\tiny S};
    \node[rectangle, draw, fill=white, right=3pt of Foo.south] {\tiny T};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which nicely yields:

[image]

But now I want to use ellipses as shapes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[ellipse, draw, inner sep=10pt] (Foo) {Foo};
    \node[ellipse, draw, fill=white, left=3pt of Foo.south] {\tiny S};
    \node[ellipse, draw, fill=white, right=3pt of Foo.south] {\tiny T};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And, unsurprisingly, the subnodes are not placed on the border anymore, but somewhat below (but they're still large enough to lap over the base node):

[image]

How would I place those subnodes exactly on the border of the base node?

Comment: this is not surprise ... your sub nodes position coordinate is wrong calculated. at ellipse they are not on the horizontal line through `foo.fouth` but higher, depend of ellipse curve. you need to determine coordinates of sub nodes accordingly.

Comment: Yes I know, the question is: how do I do that?

Comment: one way is calculate intersection between ellipse any and path from ellipse center through ellipse border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the positioning you can explicitly put them on the shape border since you want them to be as such:

```
\node[ellipse, draw, fill=white] at (Foo.-70) {\tiny T};
```

can be sufficient. If needed you can then use `shift=(<x amount>,<y amount>)` for fine tuning.